# Scala: return different type depending on parameter - withouth casting

Tags: scala

I'm trying to write a function that, based on the parameter passed in, can return different types. To use a really simple example, this is the ideal situation I'm aiming for:
Given objects such as these:

```
case object NameToken
case object SalaryToken
case object IsDirectorToken
```

and

```
val john: Employee
```

then:

- john.get(NameToken) would return "John" (a String),
- john.get(SalaryToken) would return 50000 (an Int),
- john.get(IsDirectorToken) would return false (a Boolean).

Below are a couple of possible implementations that I thought of. It goes without saying that both are horrible.

Possible implementation 1:

```
trait Token[A]
case object NameToken extends Token[String]
case object SalaryToken extends Token[Int]
case object IsDirectorToken extends Token[Boolean]

case class Employee(name: String, salary: Int, isDirector: Boolean) {
  def get[A](t: Token[A]): A = t match {
    case NameToken => name.asInstanceOf[A]
    case SalaryToken => salary.asInstanceOf[A]
    case IsDirectorToken => isDirector.asInstanceOf[A]
  }
}
```

Possible implementation 2:

```
trait Token2 {
  type returnType
}
case object NameToken2 extends Token2 {
  type returnType = String
}
case object SalaryToken2 extends Token2 {
  type returnType = Int
}
case object IsDirectorToken2 extends Token2  {
  type returnType = Boolean
}

case class Employee2(name: String, salary: Int, isDirector: Boolean) {
  def get(t: Token2): t.returnType = t match {
    case NameToken2 => name.asInstanceOf[t.returnType]
    case SalaryToken2 => salary.asInstanceOf[t.returnType]
    case IsDirectorToken2 => isDirector.asInstanceOf[t.returnType]
  }
}
```

Both of them, however, are just awful with that casting.

Can I solve this problem a little more smartly?

Thank you.

Comment: Here's a question for you. Why?

Comment: So, at compile time, the compiler has no way of knowing what type this function returns? So it will have to assume Any (common supertype of Int. Boolean, String) and so you'll have to cast it again to be able to use it as Int, Boolean or String. So you'll need to know what (run time) type it will have to do that safely. So, yes - why?

Comment: A bit long to explain how I got myself into this corner. This approach actually makes sense in the context of the domain (and it has nothing to do with employees) but I'm now satisfied that it can't be done.

Comment: Two answers below seem to meet your requirements, could you please take a look.

Comment: It is possible to have a more generic solve via macro or dependent types (I mean shapeless), have no time now to post it, will try later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class Employee(val name: String, val salary: Int, val isDirector: Boolean) {
  def get[T](t: Token[T]): T = t.value(this)
}

trait Token[T] { def value(e: Employee): T }
object NameToken extends Token[String] { def value(e: Employee) = e.name }
object SalaryToken extends Token[Int] { def value(e: Employee) = e.salary }
object IsDirectorToken extends Token[Boolean] { def value(e: Employee) = e.isDirector }
```

**Usage**

```
scala> val john = new Employee("John", 50000, false)
john: Employee = Employee@59f99ea

scala> val name = john.get(NameToken)
name: String = John

scala> val salary = john.get(SalaryToken)
salary: Int = 50000

scala> val isDirector = john.get(IsDirectorToken)
isDirector: Boolean = false
```

Comment: I would have preferred to keep the logic to extract the value inside the Employee class but this is a solution I hadn't thought of, I'm in the process of rethinking the whole approach but I've accepted your answer as it is interesting nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

You could use overloading:

```
  case class Employee(name: String, salary: Int, isDirector: Boolean) {
  def get(t: Token[String]) = name;
  def get(t: Token[Int]) = salary;
  def get(t: Token[Boolean]) = isDirector;
  }
```

Comment: You mean overloading.

Comment: you are rigth, i changed it in the answer Thanks Thomas